# Copying formulas in Google Sheets - Is it possible to alter cell references?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, copy-paste

I have a couple of questions to ask in regards to copying formulas in Google Sheets. The sheets are for a booking system for customers taking day trips and courses on our dive boats.

I have this formula with an exact date, which I need to copy into every 26th cell in column B...

Question 1. Relates to the formula below...

`=FILTER(MERQ!A:J, MERQ!D:D=date(2016,8,8))`

[Screenshot for question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ev2D.png)

Is there a way I can copy this formula so the date increases by one day every time, and at the same time the formula won't be going in the cell below, but the 26th row down each time? For example in C4, C30, C56 and so on I have to do this initially for five different boats for a year and a half, so close to 3,000 times. I just can't face changing each one individually.

Question 2. Relates to the formula below, which will display the availability from each day, for each boat.

`=MER!B3`

This time I need the formula in the cell below, but the row reference needs to change by 26 rows down each time. For example I need...

`=MER!B3` in C3
`=MER!B29` in C4
`=MER!B55`, in C5 and so on,

If I try copying the formula I get...

`=MER!B3` in C3
`=MER!B4` in C4
`=MER!B5` in C5 and so on,

[Screenshot for question 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oxOQ.png)

Again, I need to do a year and a half's worth for 5 boats, so it's dauntingly time consuming, although I think I maybe asking a question to which the answer will be that it can't be done.

Comment: I'm at the stage right now where I'm about tackle manually changing the row reference for every formula, so if anyone has any confirmation that there's no other way to do this, or vice versa, I'd welcome their input a gread deal, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second question is easier: build cell reference as a string and use it in `indirect`.

```
=indirect("MER!B" & (3 + 26*(ROW()-3)))
```

The formula uses the row of the current cell to calculate the row that you refer to.

---

The first question, about putting a formula in every 26th cell, suggests that (a) your data organization isn't the best it could be; (b) you need a [script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) to pull this off. Here is the script that sets the formulas you want in the cells C4, C30, and so on, increasing the date by 1 every time. This one sets 1000 cells (the upper limit for variable k).

```
function setFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
    sheet.getRange(4 + 26*k, 3).setFormula('=FILTER(MERQ!A:J, MERQ!D:D=date(2016,8,8)+' + k + ')');
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't even begin to thank you enough for answering both questions! The script does exactly what I need. Much appreciated, kind thanks.

Comment: I have another instance where I could use the script you kindly showed me, but because of my inexperience with scripts, so far I'm unable to adapt it correctly to work with the new formula and range. The formula which pulls the spaces on hold figure from another sheet in the same workbook, =AVL!B3 needs to go into cell B7 on MER, and then =AVL!B4 into B33 on MER, and then so on... (Every 26th row, on ColB)

Comment: You'll need to change the part `getRange(4 + 26*k, 3)`. Here the first argument is row number, the second is column number. So, to go from B7 in increments of 26, you need `getRange(7 + 26*k, 2)`

Comment: Thanks for your response! The argument re the column and row numbers makes sense, thanks. I don't like to keep asking questions here, but after more than an hour or experimenting, and searching this forum, I can't get the script to work correctly. The best I've been able to get so far is to get =AVL!C3 entered into every 26th row in ColB starting in B7. What I need is =AVL!C3 in B7, then =AVL!C4 in B33, then =AVL!C5 in B59, etc etc. Apologies for asking what I suspect is a very basic question to most, and thank you again.